# An updated IDE by snap has probably just stopped my code from working, where do even start finding a solution?

Tags: android-studio

Everything was working with my app in Android studio and I was making changes elsewhere, so I did absolutely no changes at all to my Android studio code.  Then I reboot my computer and Android Studio says it updated, it says "The IDE has been updated by snap" with no other information.

Now after this update to the IDE my app doesn't run any more.

I don't know where to start looking for a solution, does anyone have any ideas?

I don't even know what to research.

I get a massive long output of errors.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:342:82: Error: A value of type 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Animation<double>' because 'Animation<double>?' is nullable and 'Animation<double>' isn't.
 - 'Animation' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation.dart').
        final Animation<double> currentTrain = (current is TrainHoppingAnimation ? current.currentTrain : current);
                                                                                 ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:343:55: Error: A value of type 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Animation<double>' because 'Animation<double>?' is nullable and 'Animation<double>' isn't.
 - 'Animation' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation.dart').
        final Animation<double> nextTrain = nextRoute._animation;
                                                      ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:958:48: Error: The argument type 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>' because 'Animation<double>?' is nullable and 'Animation<double>' isn't.
 - 'Animation' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation.dart').
                                  widget.route.animation,
                                               ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:959:48: Error: The argument type 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>' because 'Animation<double>?' is nullable and 'Animation<double>' isn't.
 - 'Animation' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation.dart').
                                  widget.route.secondaryAnimation,
                                               ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:932:44: Error: The argument type 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>' because 'Animation<double>?' is nullable and 'Animation<double>' isn't.
 - 'Animation' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation.dart').
                              widget.route.animation,
                                           ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:933:44: Error: The argument type 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>' because 'Animation<double>?' is nullable and 'Animation<double>' isn't.
 - 'Animation' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation.dart').
                              widget.route.secondaryAnimation,
                                           ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:1685:17: Error: The argument type 'ImageFilter?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageFilter' because 'ImageFilter?' is nullable and 'ImageFilter' isn't.
 - 'ImageFilter' is from 'dart:ui'.
        filter: filter,
                ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart:3403:38: Error: The argument type 'SemanticsConfiguration?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SemanticsConfiguration' because 'SemanticsConfiguration?' is nullable and 'SemanticsConfiguration' isn't.
 - 'SemanticsConfiguration' is from 'package:flutter/src/semantics/semantics.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart').
      describeSemanticsConfiguration(_cachedSemanticsConfiguration);
                                     ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart:3603:44: Error: The argument type 'SemanticsConfiguration?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SemanticsConfiguration' because 'SemanticsConfiguration?' is nullable and 'SemanticsConfiguration' isn't.
 - 'SemanticsConfiguration' is from 'package:flutter/src/semantics/semantics.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart').
          childConfigurations.add(fragment.config);
                                           ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart:4495:31: Context: 'config' refers to a property so it couldn't be promoted.
See http://dart.dev/go/non-promo-property
  SemanticsConfiguration? get config;
                              ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart:4575:38: Error: A value of type 'SemanticsNode?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SemanticsNode' because 'SemanticsNode?' is nullable and 'SemanticsNode' isn't.
 - 'SemanticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/semantics/semantics.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart').
    final SemanticsNode node = owner._semantics;
                                     ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:1250:49: Error: A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
          ? a.foreground ?? (Paint()..color = a.color)
                                                ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:1251:49: Error: A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
          : b.foreground ?? (Paint()..color = b.color)
                                                ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:1255:49: Error: A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
          ? a.background ?? (Paint()..color = a.backgroundColor)
                                                ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:1256:49: Error: A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
          : b.background ?? (Paint()..color = b.backgroundColor)
                                                ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:1294:29: Error: A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
        ? (Paint()..color = backgroundColor)
                            ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:553:16: Context: 'backgroundColor' refers to a property so it couldn't be promoted.
See http://dart.dev/go/non-promo-property
  final Color? backgroundColor;
               ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:1343:84: Error: The argument type 'TextDirection?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextDirection' because 'TextDirection?' is nullable and 'TextDirection' isn't.
 - 'TextDirection' is from 'dart:ui'.
        final double paintOffsetAlignment = _computePaintOffsetFraction(textAlign, textDirection);
                                                                                   ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:713:1: Error: Type 'TextAffinity' not found.
TextAffinity? _toTextAffinity(String? affinity) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1038:22: Error: Type 'TextPosition' not found.
  void bringIntoView(TextPosition position);
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:716:14: Error: Undefined name 'TextAffinity'.
      return TextAffinity.downstream;
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:718:14: Error: Undefined name 'TextAffinity'.
      return TextAffinity.upstream;
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:781:77: Error: Undefined name 'TextAffinity'.
      affinity: _toTextAffinity(encoded['selectionAffinity'] as String?) ?? TextAffinity.downstream,
                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1038:22: Error: 'TextPosition' isn't a type.
  void bringIntoView(TextPosition position);
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart:262:89: Error: The argument type 'AppLifecycleState?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AppLifecycleState' because 'AppLifecycleState?' is nullable and 'AppLifecycleState' isn't.
 - 'AppLifecycleState' is from 'dart:ui'.
    final List<AppLifecycleState> generated = _generateStateTransitions(lifecycleState, state);
                                                                                        ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:574:9: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
        _currentFocalPoint,
        ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:581:9: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
        _currentFocalPoint,
        ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:626:48: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
        pointerStartLocation: _pointerLocations[_pointerQueue[0]],
                                               ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:628:46: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
        pointerEndLocation: _pointerLocations[_pointerQueue[1]],
                                             ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:634:48: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
        pointerStartLocation: _pointerLocations[_pointerQueue[0]],
                                               ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:636:46: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
        pointerEndLocation: _pointerLocations[_pointerQueue[1]],
                                             ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:643:26: Error: A value of type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
    _initialFocalPoint = _currentFocalPoint;
                         ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:706:25: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
            focalPoint: _currentFocalPoint,
                        ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:722:23: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
          focalPoint: _currentFocalPoint,
                      ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/scale.dart:736:30: Error: A value of type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
        _initialFocalPoint = _currentFocalPoint;
                             ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/multidrag.dart:138:14: Error: The argument type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
      delta: pendingDelta,
             ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/placeholder_span.dart:58:9: Error: Type 'TextBaseline' not found.
  final TextBaseline? baseline;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/placeholder_span.dart:58:9: Error: 'TextBaseline' isn't a type.
  final TextBaseline? baseline;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/placeholder_span.dart:93:33: Error: 'TextBaseline' isn't a type.
    properties.add(EnumProperty<TextBaseline>('baseline', baseline, defaultValue: null));
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/colors.dart:487:85: Error: The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
      swatch = a!._swatch.map((T key, Color color) => MapEntry<T, Color>(key, Color.lerp(color, null, t)));
                                                                                    ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/colors.dart:490:86: Error: The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
        swatch = b._swatch.map((T key, Color color) => MapEntry<T, Color>(key, Color.lerp(null, color, t)));
                                                                                     ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/colors.dart:492:86: Error: The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
        swatch = a._swatch.map((T key, Color color) => MapEntry<T, Color>(key, Color.lerp(color, b[key], t)));
                                                                                     ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:377:3: Error: Type 'Path' not found.
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
  ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:377:21: Error: Type 'Rect' not found.
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                    ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:377:33: Error: Type 'TextDirection' not found.
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:390:3: Error: Type 'Path' not found.
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
  ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:390:21: Error: Type 'Rect' not found.
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                    ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:390:33: Error: Type 'TextDirection' not found.
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:402:14: Error: Type 'Canvas' not found.
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
             ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:402:29: Error: Type 'Rect' not found.
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                            ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:402:41: Error: Type 'TextDirection' not found.
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:454:3: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  Offset valley;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:455:3: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  Offset point;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:456:3: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  Offset valleyArc1;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:457:3: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  Offset pointArc1;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:458:3: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  Offset pointArc2;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:459:3: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  Offset valleyArc2;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:488:3: Error: Type 'Path' not found.
  Path generate(Rect rect) {
  ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:488:17: Error: Type 'Rect' not found.
  Path generate(Rect rect) {
                ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:535:14: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
    required Offset center,
             ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:626:20: Error: Type 'Path' not found.
  void _drawPoints(Path path, List<_PointInfo> points) {
                   ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:659:20: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  double _getAngle(Offset a, Offset b, Offset c) {
                   ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:659:30: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  double _getAngle(Offset a, Offset b, Offset c) {
                             ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:659:40: Error: Type 'Offset' not found.
  double _getAngle(Offset a, Offset b, Offset c) {
                                       ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:377:21: Error: 'Rect' isn't a type.
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                    ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:377:33: Error: 'TextDirection' isn't a type.
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:378:11: Error: 'Rect' isn't a type.
    final Rect adjustedRect = rect.deflate(side.strokeInset);
          ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:390:21: Error: 'Rect' isn't a type.
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                    ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:390:33: Error: 'TextDirection' isn't a type.
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:402:14: Error: 'Canvas' isn't a type.
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
             ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:402:29: Error: 'Rect' isn't a type.
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                            ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:402:41: Error: 'TextDirection' isn't a type.
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:407:15: Error: 'Rect' isn't a type.
        final Rect adjustedRect = rect.inflate(side.strokeOffset / 2);
              ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:408:15: Error: 'Path' isn't a type.
        final Path path = _StarGenerator(
              ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:454:3: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
  Offset valley;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:455:3: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
  Offset point;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:456:3: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
  Offset valleyArc1;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:457:3: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
  Offset pointArc1;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:458:3: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
  Offset pointArc2;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:459:3: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
  Offset valleyArc2;
  ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:488:17: Error: 'Rect' isn't a type.
  Path generate(Rect rect) {
                ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:490:11: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
    final Offset center = rect.center;
          ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:514:11: Error: 'Path' isn't a type.
    final Path path = Path();
          ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:517:5: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
    Offset scale = Offset(rect.width / maxDiameter, rect.height / maxDiameter);
    ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:514:23: Error: The method 'Path' isn't defined for the class '_StarGenerator'.
 - '_StarGenerator' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/star_border.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Path'.
    final Path path = Path();
                      ^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:517:20: Error: The method 'Offset' isn't defined for the class '_StarGenerator'.
 - '_StarGenerator' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/star_border.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Offset'.
    Offset scale = Offset(rect.width / maxDiameter, rect.height / maxDiameter);
                   ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart:519:15: Error: The method 'Offset' isn't defined for the class '_StarGenerator'.
 - '_StarGenerator' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/star_border.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/star_border.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Offset'.
      scale = Offset(scale.dx, squash * scale.dy + (1 - squash) * scale.dx);
              ^^^^^^
```